# Extract RSSI, Lat, Lng for each TagId from log file

Tags: python

I have a  txt log file like so, and I want to extract the RSSI values, lat, long for each TagID.

```
INFO:received msg from tag : : {"tagId": "8593e96004019a2e", "anchor": [{"RSSI": -71, "ID": "P ID  00010c"}, {"RSSI": -71, "ID": "P ID  00010e"}, {"RSSI": -75, "ID": "P ID  00021d"}, {"RSSI": -77, "ID": "P ID  00010a"}, {"RSSI": -78, "ID": "P ID  000118"}, {"RSSI": -85, "ID": "P ID  00010d"}], "tagData": {"batteryLevel": 2.802}}
INFO:  {"tagId" : "8593e96004019a2e","geographic" : { "techno": "GPS", "lng": -3.707135511213621, "lat": 40.40968001418976, "alt": 0, "hdop":3},"tagSensorData" : [{"type" : "batteryLevel","value" : "2.802"}]}
```

And I want to build a csv file as follow:
tagId   ID  00010a   :ID  00021d     ID  00021f  ID  00010e ID  00010c  ID  00010d   ID  000118 lng lat batteryLevel
8593e96004019a2e    -71 -81     -90 -81 -77 -90 3.707135511213621   40.40968001418976   2.748
8593e96004019a2e    -65 -77     -83 -63 -75 -82 3.707135511213621   40.40968001418976   2.808

I don’t know how to get key, values in python. What is the best solution?
I’ve tried to export RSSI value but how to get key value?

```
import re
fi = open("log.txt", "r")
lines = fi.read()
regex = re.compile('"RSSI":\s(\-?\d+)')
out = regex.findall(lines)
print(out)
```

I’ve tried to export in json dump but how to get key, value?

```
import json
my_list = [];

with open(‘log.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # list containing lines of file
    columns = [] # To store column names

    i = 1
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip() # remove leading/trailing white spaces
        if line:
            if i == 1:
                columns = [item.strip() for item in line.split(';},')]
                i = i + 1
            else:
                d = {} # dictionary to store file data (each line)
                data = [item.strip() for item in line.split(';},')]
                for index, elem in enumerate(data):
                    d[columns[index]] = data[index]

                my_list.append(d) # append dictionary to list
#
print(json.dumps(my_list, indent=4))
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

see below. The idea is to covert the data into `dict`.

```
import json 
line = '''INFO:received msg from tag : : {"tagId": "8593e96004019a2e", "anchor": [{"RSSI": -71, "ID": "P ID  00010c"}, {"RSSI": -71, "ID": "P ID  00010e"}, {"RSSI": -75, "ID": "P ID  00021d"}, {"RSSI": -77, "ID": "P ID  00010a"}, {"RSSI": -78, "ID": "P ID  000118"}, {"RSSI": -85, "ID": "P ID  00010d"}], "tagData": {"batteryLevel": 2.802}}'''
data_json = line[line.find('{'):]
data = json.loads(data_json)
# Now you have a dict - do what ever you want with it
print(data)
```

output

```
{'tagId': '8593e96004019a2e', 'anchor': [{'RSSI': -71, 'ID': 'P ID  00010c'}, {'RSSI': -71, 'ID': 'P ID  00010e'}, {'RSSI': -75, 'ID': 'P ID  00021d'}, {'RSSI': -77, 'ID': 'P ID  00010a'}, {'RSSI': -78, 'ID': 'P ID  000118'}, {'RSSI': -85, 'ID': 'P ID  00010d'}], 'tagData': {'batteryLevel': 2.802}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but RSSI's value is not in the dict. I'm trying to extract each rssi value from ID and writing a dictionary to a csv file with one line for every 'key: value'.

Comment: @Hpatck As far as I understand - it is. See the  *output* in my answer. `'anchor': [{'RSSI': -71, 'ID': 'P ID  00010c'}`

Comment: The dictionary you get doesn't have the form of what I want to build. You don't use the keys "anchor", "RSSI", "ID" and tagData. I would have to transform the entry dictionary into a dictionary with the keys I want (which become the columns of my dataframe). Ex: From {RSSI": 71, "ID": "P ID 00010"}, I want to build "P ID 00010c": -71. 
I don't know if it's clear. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: The dict that I want shall be of the form:                                                             {"tagId": "8593e96004019a2e",
"P ID  00010c" : -71,
"P ID  00010e" : -71,
"P ID  00021d" : -75,
"P ID  00010a" : -77,
"P ID  000118" : -78,
"P ID  00010d" : -85,
"batteryLevel": 2.802
}

Comment: So the "current" dict contains the attributes you need but you need to change the dict structure?

Comment: Yes, the structure look  like:                                                                                                                  0             1             2             3             4  \
RSSI           -70           -71           -76           -78           -79   
ID    P ID  00010c  P ID  00010e  P ID  00010a  P ID  00021d  P ID  000118   

                 5  
RSSI           -85  
ID    P ID  00010d